# Closing div when clicking outside of div not working on iPhone. Works fine on Mac/PC and Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Here is the div(s). Depending on what button is clicked, one of them will appear on the screen.

```js
var box;
var value;
var wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$('body').on('click', '#login, #register', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class')) {
    value = $(this).attr('class')
  } else {
    value = $(this).attr('id')
  }
  switch (value) {
    case 'login':
      box = $('.loginBox');
      break;
    case 'register':
      box = $('.registerBox');
      break;
  }

  box.closest(wrapper).toggleClass('open');
  $('input:text', box).first().focus();
});

// this successfully closes the div when I click outside of it (on Mac/PC & Android, however it does not close the div on iOS)
$('body').on('click', '.wrapper', function() {
  box.closest(wrapper).toggleClass('open');
});
$('body').on('click', '.wrapper div', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: none;
  z-index: 300;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.blackBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 41%;
  height: 340px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 997;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blackBox">
    <div class="loginBox">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blackBox">
    <div class="registerBox">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 2nd function, (the toggle when clicking outside the div) successfully closes the div when I click outside of it (on Mac/PC & Android, however it does not close the div on iOS)

Is there another method I can perform for iOS?:

```
$('body').on('click', '.wrapper', function(){
      if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          // another method
      }
    box.closest(wrapper).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Try to use 'touchstart' instead of click..

Comment: If you put an alert inside the click handler, I mean in the second line, for example, is it working? I just to try to understand where is exactly the problem. Is it with the handler or with the `closest` / `toggleClass` area..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iStuff will only acknowledge a `click` event if the element is clickable. One of the conditions to make it clickable is to give it

```
cursor:pointer;
```

If that's not an option, you could use `tap`:

```
$(containerSelector).on('click tap', targetSelector, function(event) {
  // have you finished that webpage already?
})
```

Yet another option is to use `touchstart`. But I personally think that's a mistake. `touchstart` is triggered whenever a `touch` event is started, whether it's a **swipe**, a multi-touch **zoom** or whatever other fancy gestures your device might recognize.

Most times, when you want to swipe, pan, zoom, you don't want click functionality to trigger. `tap` is the most click-like event in the world of touch gestures.

In the particular case of a dropdown, you don't want it closing on gestures aimed at better positioning it on the screen or zooming in on the area in which it opened.

Comment: Thankyou! `.on('click tap')` actually wasn't working for me, but `cursor:pointer;` does the trick.